# databaseReference всегда null

Tags: java, android, firebase

Мне нужно достать данные из realtimeDatabase Firebase, но `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` не вызывается , потому что `databaseReference` всегда `null` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама база данных [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл `json, dependencies для firebase` я тоже добавила

достаю данные из `Firebase`:

```
 List<ParentItem> parentItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        ParentItem parentItem = new ParentItem();
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show
                (BrowseTracksActivity.this, null, "Loading Data", true);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    parentItem.setParentItemTitle(ds.child("CategoryTitle").getValue(String.class));

                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ChildItem childItem = new ChildItem();
                        childItem.setDuration(data.child("duration").getValue(String.class));
                        childItem.setAuthor(data.child("author").getValue(String.class));
                        childItem.setTrackTitle(data.child("title").getValue(String.class));
                        childItemList.add(childItem);
                    }

                    parentItem.setChildItemList(childItemList);
                    parentItemList.add(parentItem);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

так же я добавила в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: У тебя на скрине брэйк поинт стоит до инициализации базы данных, переставь его на 89 строчку, и посмотри - он уже не должен быть null.  Помоему ты не правильно извлекашь данные в onDataChange

Comment: все равно null. я обновила фото, можете там посмотреть

Comment: он даже не заходит в listener ибо я поставила  progressDialog.dismiss() и в onDataChange и onCancelled. progressDialog не перестает крутиться

Comment: Попробуй так (я гадаю) - FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category")

Comment: пробовала уже. не помогает

Comment: А проверяла если оставить просто val instance  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(), и ниже поставить точку - чтоб глянуть , инстанс то есть.

Comment: И проверить что в консоле фаирбэйз указан верный пакет приложения и в приложении верный google-services.json (можно скачать его еще раз и засунуть свеженький в приложение)

Comment: я скачивала уже несколько раз json файл и удаляла его, отключала приложение от Firebase и заново подключала уже несколько раз, поэтому там приложение указано верно

Comment: Похоже что сейчас все используют более молодежную Cloud Firestore. Лично у меня с ней особых проблем не возникало

Comment: я перешла на Firestore database, но и она не работает

Comment: На гит хабе есть проект?

Comment: спустя еще несколько часов я поняла с помощью дебаг, что приложение пытается подсоединиться к базе данных которую я давно удалила. Почему это происходит я не знаю, json File я уже удаляла и заново вставляла в проект